# How to find delta between 2 pyspark dataframes for selected columns and the others separately

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have to find the delta between 2 PySpark dataframes that affects 2 columns and the other columns too but separately. I need this because I am building an xml file out of delta.

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| ID | Company_Id | value | score | region |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1A | 3412asd | value-1 | 25 | UK |
| 2B | 2345tyu | value-2 | 34 | IE |
| 3C | 9800bvd | value-3 | 56 | US |
| 4E | 6789tvu | value-4 | 78 | IN |

and a second dataframe that looks like this:

| ID | Company_Id | value | score | region |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1A | 3412asd | value-1 | 25 | UK |
| 2B | 2345tyu | value-5 | 36 | IN |
| 3C | 9800bvd | value-3 | 56 | US |
| 4E | 6789tvu | value-4 | 81 | RU |

I want the result dataframe such that the resultant xml can be done like this. Notice that <modify_type> sub field is applied only for score, region fields and not the others. Hence I need to track deltas as mentioned in the title.

```
<action>
  <action_type>modify</action_type>
  <ID>
    <ID>2B</ID>
    <Company_Id>2345tyu</Company_Id>
    <value>value-5</value >
    <score>
      <modify_type>remove</modify_type>
      <score_value>34</score_value>
    </score>
    <score>
      <modify_type>add</modify_type>
      <score_value>36</score_value>
    </score>
    <region>
      <modify_type>remove</modify_type>
      <region_value>IE</region_value>
    </region>
    <region>
      <modify_type>add</modify_type>
      <region_value>IN</region_value>
    </region>
  </ID>

  <ID>
    <ID>4E</ID>
    <Company_Id>6789tvu</Company_Id>
    <score>
      <modify_type>remove</modify_type>
      <score_value>78</score_value>
    </score>
    <score>
      <modify_type>add</modify_type>
      <score_value>81</score_value>
    </score>
    <region>
      <modify_type>remove</modify_type>
      <region_value>IN</region_value>
    </region>
    <region>
      <modify_type>add</modify_type>
      <region_value>RU</region_value>
    </region>
</action>
```

The solution I implemented was some this like this

1. I pivoted the value, score, region columns by grouping key columns.

```
df1 = df1.select('ID', 'Company_Id', F.expr("stack(3, 'value', `value`,\
                'score', `score`,\
                'region', `region`)as (ListName, Previous_Value)" ))

df2 = df2.select('ID', 'Company_Id', F.expr("stack(3, 'value', `value`,\
                'score', `score`,\
                'region', `region`)as (ListName, Current_Value)" ))
```

2. Joined above dataframes on Key columns and compare the values.

```
df_join = df2.join(df1, (df2.Company_Id == df1.Company_Id ) & (df2.ID == df1.ID) & (df2.ListName == df1.ListName), 'inner').select(df1.ID, df1.ListName, 'Current_Value', 'Previous_Value')
```

3. This results in a dataframe that looks like this

| ID | Company_Id | ListName | Previous_Value | Current_Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1A | 3412asd | value | value-1 | value-1 |
| 1A | 3412asd | score | 25 | 25 |
| 1A | 3412asd | region | UK | UK |
| 2B | 2345tyu | value | value-2 | value-5 |
| 2B | 2345tyu | score | 34 | 36 |
| 2B | 2345tyu | region | IE | IN |
| 3C | 9800bvd | value | value-3 | value-3 |
| 3C | 9800bvd | score | 56 | 56 |
| 3C | 9800bvd | region | US | US |
| 4E | 6789tvu | value | value-4 | value-4 |
| 4E | 6789tvu | score | 78 | 81 |
| 4E | 6789tvu | region | IN | RU |

From here I use lots of case and when conditions to actually get the result.

I am trying to make this process computationally efficient.

Comment: Have you tried writing a SQL query to get the result?  Show us what you’ve tried.

Comment: Have you tried just inner joining on id and company_id, then where value <> value OR score <> score OR region <> region?

Answer (score 0):

for pyspark, you should be able to use anti join with selected columns from each DataFrame

```
df1.select(col1, col2, col4).join(df2.select(col1, col2, col4), on='ID', how='anti')
```